# Python decorators using functools.partial.. Where does "func" come from?

Tags: python, decorator, partial

Given the following python code...

```
from functools import partial

def run_n( func = None, count = 1 ):
    print( "func", func )
    print( "count", count )
    if func is None:
        return partial( run_n, count = count )
    def wrapper():
        for _ in range( count ):
            func()
    return wrapper

@run_n( count = 2 )
def func():
    print( "Hello" )

func()
```

I get the following output..

```
func None
count 2
func <function func at 0x7f6b45572ca0>
count 2
Hello
Hello
```

My question is, give that the first invocation of the `run_n` decorator has `func` None, how does the second invocation acquire `func` as the right value. I'll add that this code, less my prints, was acquired from the public source code. It seems to me that I lack the understanding of how `partial` works but I still can't see how `func` suddenly acquires a value.

Comment: "It seems to me that I lack the understanding of how partial works but I still can't see how func suddenly acquires a value" Well, what happened when you looked `functools.partial` up in the documentation? "but I still can't see how func suddenly acquires a value." Do you understand how decorators work in general? The second invocation receives `func` via the decoration process working the way it normally does: decorating `func` with `run_n(count=2)` is equivalent to doing `func = run_n(count=2)(func)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, run_n gets called with `func=None` and `n=2`. Since `func` is `None`, it will take the first branch of the if statement. `partial` then creates, and returns, an anonymous function that behaves as if it was defined like this:

```
def anonymous(*args, **kwargs):
    return run_n(*args, count=2, **kwargs)
```

Then *that* function gets called with the function being defined (i.e, the function printing "hello") as its first argument. This immediately calls

```
run_n(<func-printing-hello>,count=2)
```

This time, `run_n` has been given a `func` argument, and returns the wrapper function that calls func-printing-hello n times. This wrapper, eventually, is what gets assigned to the global `func` name.

Comment: Thank you, that has cleared it up. I'm still getting to grips with decorators and their invocation strategy.

Comment: Hey, can you explain why the first func call returns None? I tried explicitly passing in `@run_n(func=func, count=2)` and it returned with an error. I have been trying to wrap my head around it but cant really figure it out.